# .NET Framework 4.6 or above does not show up in registry

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I installed .NET 4.7 from the following link:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55168

In Visual Studio I can see that it has succesfully installed.[image]

But when I go check regedit to see determine the latest version I can't see it. There's no folder called Full under folder v4.0

[image]

I ask this because while trying to run a program I keep getting the error .NET 4.6 is not installed when I clearly installed it and the versions above. What am I missing?

Edit: Not sure if this helps but I had installed .NET 4.6.2 SDK and Targetting pack from Visual Studio 17 installer. Anything else I need to install?

When I try to install 4.7 via the link:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55170

I get an error saying installation will not occur with the reason as : '.NET Framework 4.7 or a later update is already installed on this computer.'

Comment: You did not install .NET.  A "developer pack" just contains the reference assemblies that you need to target a .NET version that you do not have installed.  Such as an ancient version like 4.0

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. From where can I download the .NET version then?  I installed 4.6 targetting pack from Visual Studio 17 installer.

Answer (score 1):

> I keep getting the error .NET 4.6 is not installed when I clearly installed it and the versions above.

The drop down list in Visual Studio does not mean you have the framework version instead, it means you have the multi-targeting pack for it installed.

To answer about the registry though, starting with the .NET Framework 4.0, things are a little different. There won't be a registry key for .NET Framework 4.5 or 4.6, or even 4.7. Instead, you need to examine the `Release` DWORD value in the registry `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full`.

The value of this DWORD determines which .NET Framework version is installed. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/how-to-determine-which-versions-are-installed) for this registry key has the values and their meaning.

For your specific case, the value "393295" means they have the .NET Framework 4.6 *or later* (such as 4.6.1 or 4.6.2) installed.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. I do not have the Full folder in the regedit even.
regarding your edit, how do I install .NET 4.6 then? I installed 4.6 targetting pack from Visual Studio 17 installer.

Comment: @Paagalpan see this page and select the appropriate link for "Redistributable Installation". Note that for Windows 10, you need to enable it through Windows Components. Visual Studio *should* have done all of this for you. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/install/guide-for-developers

Comment: When I try to install via the redistributable installation link, I get an error saying installation will not occur with the reason as : '.NET Framework 4.7 or a later update is already installed on this computer.'